# SQL Server script to traverse all tables by hierarchy/ dependency from top to bottom

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchy

I've been trying to crawl/ traverse a SQL Server database that we have to get the order of tables to populate, so far I was able to see a code using `sp_msdependencies` and used it for this purpose, you can see the actual code below.

```
DECLARE @ProductTotals TABLE
(
  oType int, 
  oObjName varchar(255),
  oOwner varchar(50),
  oSequence int
);

insert into @ProductTotals 
   EXEC sp_msdependencies @intrans = 1 ;

select 
   t.object_id as TableId
   , ist.Table_Name as TableName
   , ist.Table_Catalog as TableCatalog
   , ist.Table_Schema as TableSchema
   , pt.oSequence as [Level]
   , isnull(IDENT_CURRENT(ist.Table_Name),0) as PrimaryKeyLastValue
     , ColumnCount.NumberOfColumns as NumberOfColumns
from 
   @ProductTotals as pt
inner join 
   sys.tables as t on t.name = pt.oObjName
                   and t.is_filetable = 0
inner join 
   information_schema.tables as ist on ist.table_name = t.name
inner join
   (select 
       count(column_Name) as NumberOfColumns, Table_name
    from 
       INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
    group by 
       Table_name) as ColumnCount on ColumnCount.TABLE_Name = t.name
where 
    oType = 8
```

Now, when I ran this against a backup file of our prod DB, and followed the order of the tables I was getting an error because, it seems that some tables that are in the same level are connected by a foreign key.

Now, my assumption was that the LEVEL means that all tables in that level, regardless of the order how you will populate it, won't have problems regarding FK dependencies and were independent of each other, but I was wrong. These tables are also NOT self referencing.

I was seeing other code SQL codes that traverses the tables using CTE, but I'm getting this error

> The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted
>   before statement completion.

I guess that means that I exhausted the max loops because of self referencing tables.

I'm not really a DB person, so I would like to ask help if anyone has a SQL Server 2012 script out there that traverses all the tables and creates an order of precedence on how to populate tables that I can just `ORDER BY` and insert data into?

Been pulling my hair already for past few hours so any help will be great.

Thanks.

Comment: The maximum recursion thing can happen when you have a cycle (a table references an table that either directly or indirectly references back to the original table).  And that happens strangely a lot, I've found, no matter how much of a "bad practice" that seems. Protecting yourself against those is difficult but doable.  Just FYI.

Comment: i see, the reason is that i have to programmatically determine the order of the tables when it comes it insertion of data, and sometimes the loops are not obvious like

    * table1 references itself
    * table1 references table2 and references table3 and references table1 again

also, this DB is already in prod and i cant change things.

Comment: Honestly, when you find yourself with these kinds of requirements, it's best to back up and try to look at things from a different angle, and see if you can't find a narrowed set of requirements.  Being able to programmatically determine insert order for any conceivable tables in any conceivable database with any conceivable set of foreign keys is just not an easily solvable problem. You need to narrow, or split up, the problem space.